# Deleting user-defined vectors - C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, delete-operator, user-defined

I have 2 classes, say A & B. Class B has a destructor of its own. Within class A, I have a vector of pointers to objects of class B. The vector is as follows:

```
vector<B*> vect;
```

In the destructor for class A, how do I retrieve memory? If I cycle through the vector, do I retrieve each object and use delete on every retrieved object? I tried that out in the destructor, but it segfaults.

Any help in solving this problem is most welcome. I am sorry but I cannot post the code.

Comment: Before we answer that question. We must know how you put things into the vector (are the objects created with new (this opens another question who owns the objects you just created?)). Another question is why are you putting pointers in a vector. The vector is designed to take ownership of 'Objects' so unless your B are polymorphic it may be better to put B objects (not pointers) into the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other posts pointed out that you're better of using smart pointers instead of pointers. If you have to use pointer for any reason whatsoever you should delete them in a loop first.

```
for ( std::vector<B*>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
    delete (*it);
vect.clear();
```

edit:
If your program segfault in the destructor then your code is wrong. Maybe you put stack element by adress in the vector, but to delete an object it has to be on the heap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class data {
public:
    std::string d;
    data(std::string _d) : d(_d) { }
};

class container {
public:
    std::vector<data*> c;
    container() { c.clear(); }
    void add (data *d) { c.push_back(d); }
    ~container() {
        for (std::vector<data*>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
            delete (*it); 
        c.clear();
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    typedef std::vector<std::string> sVec;
    typedef sVec::iterator sVecIter;

    std::vector<std::string> cmd (argv+1, argv+argc);

    {
    container k;            
    for (sVecIter it = cmd.begin(); it != cmd.end(); ++it)
        k.add(new data((*it)));

    }

    return 0;

}
```

This works without problem.

Answer (score 3):

If A owns the things pointed to by `vect`, then it should be able to `delete` each item within `vect`.  If it segfaults while doing so, then you have a bug somewhere in your code.

In general, though, you're better off using smart pointers.  Boost's [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) (part of [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) is designed for your specific example, but a simple `std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<B> >`will also work (albeit with more overhead and a more awkward syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the items of type `B*` point to objects allocated on the heap, then for each item you should call delete on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would loop the vector and delete each item.  The problem is that you forgot the towel operator on line 42.

Comment: huh, 'The problem is that you forgot the towel operator on line 42.'

Comment: What is this "you forgot the towel operator on line 42" stuff all about? Is it some in joke?

Comment: @robin: A nice hitchhikers guide reference - which i'd rather see in a comment though.

Comment: The OP says that they tried to loop the vector and delete each object within the destructor of A but got a segfault....but they won't supply code.  So I used my ESP powers to find the problem and provided them with the correct fix.

Comment: @Georg: Thanks for clarifying, that's been driving me nuts. Strangely I don't remember that quote, perhaps I should read it again...

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid storing pointers in containers when you need to manage their lifetime.

If this is the one true owner and is guaranteed to be last to cleanup then I'd go with

```
std::vector<B> vect;
```

If you have different references and lifetimes that may overlap then shared_ptr would be better (std::tr1 or boost depending on compiler)

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<B> > vect;
```

Answer (score -1):

From your description it sounds like your vect member of class A should have lifetime ownership of the data pointed by the B*.

I would recommend just changing that declaration to

```
vector< std::tr1::shared_ptr<B> > vect;
```

EDIT: replaced auto_ptr with std::tr1::shared_ptr

Comment: `vector` plus `auto_ptr` is a bad idea: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm

Comment: `auto_ptr` is not suitable for standard containers, because of its odd copy behavior.

Comment: `std::tr1::shared_ptr` would be better.